# Leaking memory in word frequency program

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I'm leaking a very small amount of memory in a wf function I'm writing, and I can't seem to exactly locate it. I'm using a hash table to hold freqency, but my testing makes it look like it's not in the hashing functions. Here are my functions to open/read files and free the data at the end. I'm sure it's a simple bug, but I've been looking at this code too long to be able to see it.

```
typedef struct {
   int noInFiles, numFiles, numToPrint;
   char** fileNames;
   FILE** files;
   Hash hash;
} Freq;

void handleInput(int argc, char* argv[], Freq* freq) {
   int num = 0, i, j = 0;
   char* crap;

   printf("memcurrent pre fileName alloc: %d\n\n", memCurrent());
   freq->fileNames = calloc(argc - 1, sizeof(char**));
   printf("memcurrent post filename alloc: %d\n\n", memCurrent());
   freq->numToPrint = 10;

   if(argc < 2) {
      freq->noInFiles = 1;
      freq->numFiles = 0;
      return;
   }

   for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      if(argv[i][0] == '-') {
         if(argv[i][1] == 'n') {
            num = strtol(argv[i] + 2, &crap, 10);
            freq->numToPrint = num;
         }
         else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: wf [-nX] [file...]\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
      }
      else {
         freq->fileNames[j] = calloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1 ,sizeof(char));
         strcpy(freq->fileNames[j], argv[i]);
         j++;
         freq->numFiles++;
      }
   }
}

void openFiles(Freq* freq) {
   int i;
   char* str;

   printf("Memcurrent pre open: %d\n",memCurrent());
   freq->files = calloc(freq->numFiles,sizeof(FILE**));
   printf("Memcurrent post open: %d\n",memCurrent());

   for(i = 0; i < freq-> numFiles; i++) {
      freq->files[i] = fopen(freq->fileNames[i],"r");
      if(freq->files[i] == NULL) {
         str = malloc(strlen(freq->fileNames[i]) + 5);
         sprintf(str,"wf: %s",freq->fileNames[i]);
         perror(str);
         free(str);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   }
}

void freeFreq(int argc, Freq* freq) {
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < argc - 1 ; i++) {
      free(freq->fileNames[i]);
   }
   free(freq->fileNames);
   free(freq->files);
}
```

Hash functions

```
typedef struct {
   Entry* arr;
   int size, numValid;
} Hash;

void initHash(Hash* hash) {
   hash->arr = calloc(BASESIZE, sizeof(Entry));
   TOTALALLOC =+ (BASESIZE * sizeof(Entry));
   hash->size = BASESIZE;
   hash->numValid = 0;
}

void freeTable(Hash* hash) {
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < hash->numValid - 1; i++) {
      if(hash->arr[i].correct == 1 && hash->arr[i].valid == 1) {
         wordsFreed++;
         free(hash->arr[i].word);
      }
   }
   free(hash->arr);
}
```

Comment: Should that be `strtol(argv[i] + 1,` instead of +2?

Comment: What is `Hash`? Please provide a compilable example.

Comment: Quibble: `calloc(..., FILE**)` should be FILE* (one *).

Comment: @AustinHastings no, that value works fine, it's getting an input flag formatted [-nX] where X is the value I want

Comment: OIC. Sorry, I was parsing it as [i+2] instead of [i]+strlen("-n")

Comment: I don't see you creating or freeing the `Hash` object. And your free does not release `freq`, either. Otherwise, I don't see anything.

Comment: Freq is not allocated, it's initialized in main as a struct, not a struct*

Comment: I also threw in the hash initialization and freeing

Comment: @EvanCooper "that value works fine" You are getting away with it because `sizeof(FILE*)` happens to be the same as `sizeof(FILE**)` on your platform. The correct expressions would be `sizeof(FILE*)` and `sizeof(char*)`. You do know how to call `calloc` correctly when allocating an array of something that are not pointers, why add a spurious star in this case?

Comment: @EvanCooper why don't you just put the whole program on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/)?  You might want to perform error checking on `strol()`. @AustinHastings, `freq` is just a function argument, and `Freq` is a static struct, it's not dynamically allocated. Also, you might wanna make this line `freq->fileNames = calloc(argc - 1, sizeof(char**));` look like `freq->fileNames = calloc(argc - 1, sizeof (char *));`. Each element of `fileNames[]` is holding a *pointer to a char*.

Comment: Can you use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  If so, do so; it will tell you what was leaked and where it was allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be it:

```
for(i = 0; i < hash->numValid - 1; i++) {
```

If you have numValid set to 0 at start, I'm presuming that you increment it each time you add an entry to the array.

So if numValid is 1, then you will never loop, which means you will leak one of your entries. It seems that each time you free the hash, you will leak one entry, unless the hash has no entries at all.

Answer (score 1):

This may not fix your problem, but ..

There is a mismatch between the number of allocations and deallocations for `freq->fileNames`.

Allocation:

```
  else {
     freq->fileNames[j] = calloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1 ,sizeof(char));
     strcpy(freq->fileNames[j], argv[i]);
     j++;
     freq->numFiles++;
  }
```

Deallocation:

```
for(i = 0; i < argc - 1 ; i++) {
   free(freq->fileNames[i]);
}
```

Assuming the logic for allocation is correct, the logic for deallocation needs to be:

```
for(i = 0; i < freq->numFiles ; i++) {
   free(freq->fileNames[i]);
}
```

**PS**

I noticed that you have calls to `fopen` but no calls to `fclose` in your posted code.

Comment: `calloc` returns 0-filled memory.

Comment: to your PS, the files are all closed after being counted, in the counting function